# How can I make my javascript function wait for the results of an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I am writing an APIService class to help me with having a standardized way for AJAX requests for my web application. The httpRequest function expression is working correctly. When I make a second call to ApiService.call, it works correctly because the endpoints have been set. BTW - I am defining this as a static class so that it can be referenced without being instantiated.

I am having a problem with the call method in ApiService. Specifically, when I call ApiService.setEndpoints, ApiService.endpoints.store_get (the default endpoint created when I run the setEndpoint method) has not been set when I make the httpRequest.

I know that you should pass a callback if data needs to be set, however, I do not know how best to do this in this circumstance.

```
var ApiService = 
{
    endpoints: {
    },

    ENUMERATE_ENDPOINT:'/apis/abc/0.1/json/Resource/Enumerate/init',

    init:function()
    {
    },

    setEndpoints:function()
    {
        try {
            new httpRequest(ApiService.ENUMERATE_ENDPOINT,'','GET',ApiService.constructEndpoint,true);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('Error making AJAX call to set API endpoints');
            console.log('Error message: ' + e.message)
        }
    },

    constructEndpoint:function(data)
    {
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        if (json.hasOwnProperty('success') && (json.success == 'TRUE' )) {
            // Sets the api endpoints
            for (endpoint in json.payload.api_endpoints) {
                ApiService.endpoints[endpoint] = json.payload.api_domains.api_root_url.slice(json.payload.api_domains.api_root_url.indexOf('apis')) 
                                                + json.payload.api_endpoints[endpoint];
            }               
        }
    },

    call:function(params, callback, endpoint_string)
    {
        endpoint_string = endpoint_string || undefined;

        try {
            if (typeof endpoint_string !== "undefined") {
                new httpRequest(endpoint_string, params, 'POST', callback, true);
            } else {        
                ApiService.setEndpoints();
                new httpRequest(ApiService.endpoints.store_get, params, 'POST', callback, true);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('Error making AJAX call to API endpoints');
            console.log('Error message: ' + e.message);
        }
    }
}

var httpRequest = function(url,params,method,callback,async)
```

BTW - I know that I can set async to false in the setEndpoints function, but I don't want to degrade the performance of my api

Comment: I'm a little confused by your description, but if your functions aren't ready to run you can put them in a local queue and process the queue when the API call is done. If the API call has already run, then you can skip the queue altogether and just execute the function immediately. You can maintain a state variable that defaults to false to determine if you need to queue or not (i.e. isReady = false). if (isReady) { // ... execute } else { // ... add to queue }

Comment: Yes, make `setEndpoints` take a callback. And you'll need an anonymous function wrapper around the `constructEndpoint` function that is passed as the callback to `httpRequest`.